# python replace ; with , if line starts with keyword

Tags: python, replace

I have a textfile containing thousands of entries like:

```
@INBOOK{Abu-Lughod1991,
  chapter = {Writing against culture},
  pages = {137-162},
  title = {Recapturing anthropology},
  publisher = {School of American Research Press},
  year = {1991},
  editor = {Richard Fox},
  author = {Abu-Lughod, Lila},
  address = {Santa Fe /NM},
  abstract = {Im Zusammenhang mit der Debatte um die writing culture fomuliert AL
        eine feministische Kritik und zeigt, wie von dort doch Anregungen
        für die Reflektion der Schreibweise und Repräsentation gekommen sind.*},
  crossref = {Rabinow1986},
  keywords = {Frauen; Feminismus; Erzählung als EG; Repräsentation; Roman; Schreibtechnik;
        James Clifford; writing culture; Dialog;},
  owner = {xko},
  systematik1 = {Anth\theor\Ethnographie},
  systematik2 = {Anth\theor\Text & Ges},
  timestamp = {1995-12-02}
}
```

I will replace all semicolons in the keywords - field to comma. But only in the keywords field - other fields should be untouched:

```
keywords = {Frauen, Feminismus, Erzählung als EG, Repräsentation, Roman, Schreibtechnik, James Clifford, writing culture, Dialog,},
```

I'm not a programmer and maybe the following code-snippet is a good starting point and i would really appreciate if someone could complete it.

```
outfile = open("literatur_comma.txt", "w") 
for line in open("literatur_semicolon.txt", "r"): 
    if line  # starts with "keywords" replace all semicolon with comma
        outfile.write(line) # write in new file
outfile.close()
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: 
Thanks for all your answers and codes, that's great!
I did a mistake in my thoughts and if i use my code-wrapper (with outfile), then it creates a new file with the keywords in it.
How can i use the same file and replaces only the semicolons to comma in keywords line?

Comment: Your `keywords` spans multiple lines if this is a Bibtex file (which it looks like).  Is that the case in your actual file as well?  If that's the case, it makes the problem significantly more complicated.

Comment: Is there a reason you want this in Python specifically? It's a fine language but if you over-constrain the question you may not get the best answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this works for a single line.

```
if line.strip().startswith('keywords'):
    line = line.replace(';',',')
outfile.write(line)
```

If keywords spans multiple lines in your actual text file though, this won't get the job done.

Comment: @johnthexiii -- I have a feeling that this is heading toward a somewhat complicated regex to handle the line wrapping inside the curly braces.

Comment: if i use this code, then it creates a new file with the keywords.
How can i use the same file and replaces only the semicolons to comma in keywords line?

Comment: The typical way is to create a new file and then use `shutil.move` to move the new file on top of the old file.  It could be done in place since you're replacing 1 character with another, but that's a much more difficult problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
outfile = open("literatur_comma.txt", "w") 
for line in open("literatur_semicolon.txt", "r"): 
    if line.startswith('keywords'):  # starts with "keywords" replace all semicolon with comma
        outfile.write(line.replace(';',',')) # write in new file
outfile.close()
```

Comment: how can i avoid to write in new file and just replace the semicolon in original file?

Answer (score 0):

**using pyparsing**

Note: this is one way to do it, but brain isn't in parsing mode - so this is an *idea* rather than a *proper* answer... It certainly needs some work, but might well be the right direction...

A somewhat messy example of using `pyparsing`... (could be much nicer, with some @INBOOK and wotsit checking and parsing, but anyway...)

```
from pyparsing import *

keywords = originalTextFor(Keyword('keywords') + '=')
values = delimitedList(Regex('[^;}]+'), ';')
values.setParseAction(lambda L: ', '.join(L))
```

Where `text` is your example:

```
>>> print values.transformString(text)
@INBOOK{Abu-Lughod1991,
  chapter = {Writing against culture},
  pages = {137-162},
  title = {Recapturing anthropology},
  publisher = {School of American Research Press},
  year = {1991},
  editor = {Richard Fox},
  author = {Abu-Lughod, Lila},
  address = {Santa Fe /NM},
  abstract = {Im Zusammenhang mit der Debatte um die writing culture fomuliert AL
        eine feministische Kritik und zeigt, wie von dort doch Anregungen
        für die Reflektion der Schreibweise und Repräsentation gekommen sind.*},
  crossref = {Rabinow1986},
  keywords = {Frauen, Feminismus, Erzählung als EG, Repräsentation, Roman, Schreibtechnik, James Clifford, writing culture, Dialog;},
  owner = {xko},
  systematik1 = {Anth   heor\Ethnographie},
  systematik2 = {Anth   heor\Text & Ges},
  timestamp = {1995-12-02}
```